# Webapp requesting access to a specific repo

Tags: github, gitlab

I want to write an app that has read/write access to a user's specific repository (Gitlab and Github).

Ideally, the user simply gives a link to the repository, and by clicking a confirmation button (providing the user's logged in to Gitlab/Github), the webapp gets read/write access to that specific repo. (So just like an OAuth flow, but only for one repo).

Is this possible? If not, what would be the best (i.e. frictionless) way of having users grant an external app access to a their repo?

Answer (score 0):

This use case is covered by [OAuth applications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#introduction-to-oauth).

When configured, GitLab users can provide authorization to your web app to take API actions on their behalf (with the authorized scope). Unfortunately, there is no in-built mechanism to limit this to a single project from GitLab. You can, however, have [group owned applications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#group-owned-applications).

Alternatively, you could implement per-repo access as a feature in *your* application, rather than in the GitLab authorization flow.

GitLab administrators can also mark registered applications as "trusted" and users won't be prompted to allow the authorization from GitLab to your app. This has the benefit of being more frictionless, but should only be used for apps you control or trust.